# Compile C++ undefine reference in Visual Studio Code on WSL2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've downloaded [C++ github project](https://github.com/yge58/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding) to start using it in Visual Studio Code using git clone in WSL2 installed in Win10 system. Testing helloworld (according to Microsoft manual) works fine, starting it using make in WSL console fine too, yet I cannot start C++ project in VSC using any compiler settings.

I either getting main does not exist error or file format not recognized.

If Open WSL window -> path to project in WSL2 -> F5 -> Select enviroment -> C++ (GDB/LLDB) -> g++ then build error main does not exist

```
   Starting build... /usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/main.cpp
-o /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/main /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWN4mTK.o: in function `aStar(Agent&, Map&)': /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:51: undefined reference to `Map::getNeighbors(Node const&, std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> >&)' /usr/bin/ld: /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:63: undefined reference to `Map::isObstacle(Node const&)' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWN4mTK.o: in function `get_true_distance_heuristic(Agent&, Map&, Node const&)': /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:101: undefined reference to `Map::isObstacle(Node const&)' /usr/bin/ld: /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:130: undefined reference to `Map::getNeighbors(Node const&, std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> >&)' /usr/bin/ld: /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:142: undefined reference to `Map::isObstacle(Node const&)' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWN4mTK.o: in function `print_fScore(Agent const&, Map&)': /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:197: undefined reference to `Map::isObstacle(Node const&)' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWN4mTK.o: in function `print_gScore(Agent const&, Map&)': /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:230: undefined reference to `Map::isObstacle(Node const&)' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWN4mTK.o: in function `print_space_map(std::vector<std::unordered_map<Node, Agent*, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, Agent*> > >, std::allocator<std::unordered_map<Node, Agent*, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, Agent*> > > > > const&, Map&)': /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:326: undefined reference to `Map::print_map_with_agents(std::unordered_map<Node, Agent*, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, Agent*> > > const&)' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWN4mTK.o: in function `check_collision_type2(std::unordered_map<Node, std::vector<Agent*, std::allocator<Agent*> >, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, std::vector<Agent*, std::allocator<Agent*> > > > > const&, std::unordered_map<Node, std::vector<Agent*, std::allocator<Agent*> >, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, std::vector<Agent*, std::allocator<Agent*> > > > >&, std::vector<std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> >, std::allocator<std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> > > >&)': /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:355: undefined reference to `Agent::getNextNode(Node const&, Node&)' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWN4mTK.o: in function `fix_pair(std::unordered_map<Node, std::vector<Agent*, std::allocator<Agent*> >, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, std::vector<Agent*, std::allocator<Agent*> > > > >&, std::unordered_map<Node, std::vector<Agent*, std::allocator<Agent*> >, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, std::vector<Agent*, std::allocator<Agent*> > > > >&, Node, Node&, Map&)': /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:412: undefined reference to `Map::get_clean_neighbors(Node const&, std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> >&)' /usr/bin/ld: /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:413: undefined reference to `Map::get_clean_neighbors(Node const&, std::vector<Node, std::allocator<Node> >&)' /usr/bin/ld: /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:462: undefined reference to `Agent::insert_path_after_front(std::__cxx11::list<Node, std::allocator<Node> > const&)' /usr/bin/ld: /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:490: undefined reference to `Agent::insert_path_after_front(std::__cxx11::list<Node, std::allocator<Node> > const&)' /usr/bin/ld: /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:492: undefined reference to `Agent::print_path()' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWN4mTK.o: in function `update_space_map(std::vector<std::unordered_map<Node, Agent*, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, Agent*> > >, std::allocator<std::unordered_map<Node, Agent*, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, Agent*> > > > >&, Agent*)': /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/include/util.hpp:528: undefined reference to `Agent::get_portion_path(std::__cxx11::list<Node, std::allocator<Node>
>&)' /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWN4mTK.o: in function `main': /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `Map::Map(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)' /usr/bin/ld: /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `Map::printMap()' /usr/bin/ld: /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/main.cpp:69: undefined reference to `Agent::set_portion_path(std::vector<std::unordered_map<Node, Agent*, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, Agent*> > >, std::allocator<std::unordered_map<Node, Agent*, std::hash<Node>, std::equal_to<Node>, std::allocator<std::pair<Node const, Agent*> > > > > const&)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
```

Launch.json generated for (1):

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Yet I can start this project using

> make -j8

and

> ./bin/coop_astar

commands in Ubuntu or even Visual Studio Code, so I don't understand why it cannot be successfully compiled.

Note: include to .hpp files was edited to

```
#include "include/common.hpp"
#include "include/Agent.hpp"
#include "include/Map.hpp"
#include "include/util.hpp"
```

All other codelines are same.

Comment: I think you have a problem in your code specifically `include/Map.hpp` appears to declare functions but not implement them.

Comment: The implementation of Map is in: [https://github.com/yge58/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/blob/master/src/Map.cxx](https://github.com/yge58/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/blob/master/src/Map.cxx) please show how you are compiling this file. You probably need to show your `tasks.json`

Comment: In /src/Map.cxx #include "Map.hpp" was edited to #include "../include/Map.hpp"

Then I tried to debug Map.cxx and get

/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/src/Map.cxx -o /home/vlad/diplom/examples/collaborative_a_star_pathfinding/src/Map
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tasks.json there (hope link works) 
https://telegra.ph/drescherjm-tasksjson-03-23